# Azure Cognitive Speech TTS Custom Japanese Non-Neural Voice Unavailable

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I'm on the S0 Tier for Azure Cognitive Speech services and am trying to train a custom voice for Japanese TTS. My data was successfully processed. But I wasn't able to select "Statistical Parametric" or "Concatenative" as my training method. "Neural" was the only option on the list.

[Training Method Options for Japanese model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi6bM.png)

However, I was able to use those non-neural methods for English and Chinese projects.

[Training Method Options for English/Chinese model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xyO9.png)

Does anyone know if I could still train a Japanese non-neural voice model? If so, how?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Non-Neutral voice training has been deprecated. The standard/non-neural training tier (adaptive, statistical parametric, concacenative) of Custom Voice is being deprecated. The announcement has been sent out to all existing Speech subscriptions before 2/28/2021. During the deprecation period (3/1/2021 - 2/29/2024), existing standard tier users can continue to use their non-neural models created. All new users/new speech resources should move to the neural tier/Custom Neural Voice. After 2/29/2024, all standard/non-neural custom voices will no longer be supported.

To answer your question about why you can train non-neutral for English and Chinese projects but not for Japanese: We allow current users to re-train non-neural voices for their existing projects, but they are not allowed to train new for non-neutral.

For user use non-neutral, we have a short guidance to help you mitigate to neutral training:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-voice#migrate-to-custom-neural-voice

Sorry for the inconvenience.